# how I can replace backslashes in python

Tags: python

I simply wanna replace the backslash but I can't , I searched  every where but nothing found

I tried:

```
mystr = "\n"

mystr.replace("\\",'x') #nothing happened

print(mystr.startswith('\\')) #False

print(ord('\')) #EOL_Error

print(ord(mystr[0]) == ord('\\')) #False
```

can any one help me pleas ..

Comment: There's no backslash in that string. `\n` is an escape sequence that's parsed as a newline character.

Comment: '\n' does not contain a backslash. It is one character. You can test this yourself with `ord('\n')`

Answer (score 3):

```
# This string contains no backslashes; it's a single linebreak.
mystr = "\n"
# Hence this does nothing:
mystr.replace("\\", 'x') 
# and this is False:
print(mystr.startswith('\\'))

# This is a syntax error because the \ escapes the '
print(ord('\')) #EOL Err

# This is still False because there's still no '\\` in mystr
print(ord(mystr[0]) == ord('\\')) #False
```

If you use the `\\` escape consistently you get the results you're looking for:

```
# This string contains a backslash and an n.
mystr = '\\n'
# Now this prints "xn":
print(mystr.replace('\\', 'x'))
# and this is True:
print(mystr.startswith('\\'))

# This prints 92
print(ord('\\'))

# This is also True:
print(ord(mystr[0]) == ord('\\'))
```

You can define `mystr` as a raw string (making `'\n'` a literal `\` followed by `n`), but this doesn't work for strings like `'\'` because even in a raw string, the `\` escapes any quotation mark immediately following it.  For a string *ending* in `\` you still need to use a normal escape sequence.

```
mystr = r'\n'
print(mystr.replace('\\', 'x'))
print(mystr.startswith('\\'))

print(ord('\\'))
print(ord(mystr[0]) == ord('\\'))
```

Comment: thank you very much for your explaination I realy apreaciate it  <3

Comment: isn't there any trick to add '\' to a string (e.g): text = 'n' ; text[0] = '\'

Comment: Strings are immutable, you can't modify them by subscripting the way you can a list.  Do `text = '\\' + text` if you want to prepend a `'\'` to `text`.